# Tomcat: deleting content of "logs" and "tmp" directories

Tags: logging, tomcat, tmp

I have noticed that "logs" and "tmp" content take 36GB and 21GB respectively. I need to free up some disk space and currently wondering is it vise to clean them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete logs older than 7 days.

```
find tomcat/logs/ -mtime +7 -print0 | xargs -r -0 rm -rf
```

You probably want to add this as a cronjob too.

Before deleting temp-files, you should make sure that nothing is holding them open.

Comment: `find ... -execdir rm {} +` is cleaner, and `find ... -delete` even more so, if they are available.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up tomcat in logrotate properly.  Something like this as /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat:

```
/var/log/tomcat/*.log /var/log/tomcat/*.out {  
 copytruncate  
 daily  
 rotate 7  
 compress  
 missingok
}
```

tmp you might want to sweep using the find command that pkhamre showed, but I would use logrotate on the log files.  You didn't say which distro you're using, but RHEL/CentOS has tmpwatch, which will remove files that haven't been accessed for a defined period of time.

Comment: If the filenames already have dates/times in them logrotate will consider each one a separate log and not do what you want.